# C++ code compiled with g++ works, but XCode fails

Tags: c++, xcode, compiler-errors, armadillo

I'm trying to compile a small C++ example in XCode 12.5.1 using the linear algebra library [armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net), which I've installed without problems:

```
//example.cpp

#include <armadillo>
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;
using namespace arma;

int
main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    cout << "Armadillo version: " << arma_version::as_string() << endl;
  
    cx_vec eigval;
    cx_mat eigvec;
    mat A(3,3,fill::zeros);
    eig_gen(eigval, eigvec, A);
    
    cout << A << "\n";
    cout << eigval << "\n";
    cout << eigvec << "\n";
  
    return 0;
}
```

Specifically, I'm trying to figure out why the inclusion function `eig_gen()` gives me linking errors in XCode (removing the function call allows for proper compilation):

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_dgeev_", referenced from:
      void arma::lapack::geev<double>(char*, char*, int*, double*, int*, double*, double*, double*, int*, double*, int*, double*, int*, int*) in main.o
  "_dgeevx_", referenced from:
      void arma::lapack::geevx<double>(char*, char*, char*, char*, int*, double*, int*, double*, double*, double*, int*, double*, int*, int*, int*, double*, double*, double*, double*, double*, int*, int*, int*) in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Since if I compile the program using g++ on the command line,`g++ example.cpp -o example -std=c++11 -O2 -larmadillo`, the compilation is successful and the program outputs:

```
Armadillo version: 10.6.2 (Keep Calm)
        0        0        0
        0        0        0
        0        0        0

                      (0,0)
                      (0,0)
                      (0,0)

    (+1.000e+00,+0.000e+00)    (+1.000e+00,-0.000e+00)                      (0,0)
    (+0.000e+00,+1.000e+00)    (+0.000e+00,-1.000e+00)                      (0,0)
                      (0,0)                      (0,0)    (+1.000e+00,+0.000e+00)
```

The only change I made to XCode's default linking setup (the project is a `Command Line Tool` project) is to include `/usr/local/include` in `System Header Search Paths`, so that I can use the code's first line `#include <armadillo>`.

Any suggestions as to why XCode specifically might be giving me this error?

############################### Update

I've noticed that if I place the definition `#define ARMA_DONT_USE_WRAPPER` in the fist line of the program above `#include <armadillo>`, then the command-line compilation using g++ also outputs the same linking errors. This suggests to me that the error is related to armadillo.

Comment: Try cleaning out `/usr/local/include` completely and be careful with reinstalling any headers there. It looks like something in `/usr/local/include` is interfering with LAPACK definitions, or is redefining LAPACK functions. Do you encounter any compiler warnings when using Xcode?  (may need to add `-Wall` to compiler flags)

Comment: It's also possible that Xcode itself is interfering with LAPACK definitions. Check all enabled flags and frameworks.  Some may be enabled by default, or enabled implicitly, etc.

Comment: @mtall Thanks for the suggestions. There are no compiler warnings. Unfortunately, clearing out the include directory and using `-Wall` did not solve the problem. I couldn't find anything in XCode that might preclude it from compiling properly, but will continue searching.

Comment: Update: I've noticed that if I place the definition `#define ARMA_DONT_USE_WRAPPER` in the fist line of the program above `#include <armadillo>`, then the command-line compilation using g++ also outputs the same linking errors. This suggests to me that the error is related to armadillo.

Comment: If you're using `ARMA_DONT_USE_WRAPPER`, you need make sure that Xcode is configured to use the Accelerate framework (Apple's implementation of BLAS and LAPACK). Otherwise you need to configure Xcode to link with the Armadillo runtime library. This is different from the armadillo header file.